# How to iterate through a dictionary pandas where values are tuples, and find first True and False values

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, pandas, tuples

I have a dictionary called `weeks_adopted` where when I run `iteritems()` and print the `value`, I get (example of the values for 3 keys, each key is called `app_id`). The `weeks_adopted` dict consists of key value pairs where the key is of type `<type 'str'>`and the value is a `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` where `dtype` is `bool`. Here is one example of one `value`, where the indices are basically the week referred to (weeks 0-13 of the year in order):

```
Name: app_id_str, dtype: bool
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9      True
10    False
11    False
12     True
13    False
Name: app_id_str, dtype: bool
0     False
1     False
2     False
3      True
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11    False
12    False
13    False
Name: app_id_str, dtype: bool
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11     True
12     True
13     True
```

What I want to do is calculate the number of rows from the first `True` value right through to the first `False` value, for each key, obviously accounting for each cases for example in the 3rd tuple you see the first `True` after the first `False`. Basically this is to do with drop out rates - when does a user first see something (True) and then give it up (False).

In the example of the tuples above, the result should be 1, 1 and 3 in terms of adoption rate.

Here is my current basic method:

```
for key,value in weeks_adopted.iteritems():
    start= value.index(True)
    end = value.index(False)
    adoption=end-start
    weeks_adopted[key] = adoption
```

However I get this error even with this method:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-608c4f533e54> in <module>()
     19 for key,value in weeks_adopted.iteritems():
     20     print value
---> 21     start= value.index(True)
     22     end = value.index(False)
     23     adoption=end-start

TypeError: 'Int64Index' object is not callable
```

In the answer, please could you help me in what other checks I need to be doing to find the first True and first Last value? I am presuming this type of loop is a common one for many situations?

Comment: What exactly is the structure of `weeks_adopted`? Dictionary of tuples with int and boolean pairs? A tuple of dictionaries with just boolean values? Please provide defined, reproducible structure and not looped output.

Comment: Hi @Parfait, see changes made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
def calc_adoption(ts):
    true_index = ts[ts].index
    if len(true_index) == 0:
        return 0
    first_true_index = true_index[0]
    false_index = ts.index.difference(true_index)
    false_index = false_index[false_index > first_true_index]
    if len(false_index) == 0:
        return 14 - first_true_index
    return false_index[0] - first_true_index

adopted_weeks = {k: calc_adoption(v) for k, v in weeks_adopted.iteritems()}
```

Comment: Thanks, this logic makes sense, getting   `File "<ipython-input-32-a590e23452f6>", line 31
    adopted_weeks = [k: calc_adoption(v) for k, v in weeks_adopted.iteritems()]
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax` however?

Comment: Got it! I used `test={}

for k,v in weeks_adopted.iteritems():
    test[k] = calc_adoption(v)`